# Javascript doesn't see inputs value

Tags: javascript

I have some form in my app with some inputs.

```
<input id="diploma" class="span4" value="123"></input>
```

When I try to output value:

```
console.log($("#diploma").val());
```

it is empty string. However I have a lot of inputs in my form which value I get succesfully.
Here is full code:

```
<script>
$("#save").click(function(){
    var ticketNumber=$("#ticketNumber").val();
    var paymentDate=$("#paymentDate").val();
    var issueDate=$("#issueDate").val();
    var fio=$("#fio").val();
    var birthDate=$("#birthDate").val();
    var workNumber=$("#workNumber").val();
    var mobileNumber=$("#mobileNumber").val();
    var email=$("#email").val();
    var lpu=$("#lpu").val();
    var structuralSubdivision=$("#lpu").val();
    var position=$("#position").val();
    var category=$("#category").val();
    var categoryDate=$("#categoryDate").val();
    var diploma=$("#diploma").val());
    var speciality=$("#speciality").val();
    var degree=$("#degree").val();
    var secondDiploma=$("#secondDiploma").val();
    console.log($("#diploma").val());
    form={ticketNumber:ticketNumber,paymentDate:paymentDate,issueDate:issueDate,fio:fio,birthDate:birthDate,workNumber:workNumber,mobileNumber:mobileNumber,email:email,lpu:lpu,structuralSubdivision:structuralSubdivision,position:position,category:category,categoryDate:categoryDate,diploma:diploma,speciality:speciality,degree:degree,secondDiploma:secondDiploma};
$.ajax({
        url : "add.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : form,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {

        },
        });
});
</script>
<div id="numberOfCertificate" class="span12">
<div class="row">
    <p class="span4" >Номер удостоверения</p>
    <p  class="span4">оплачено</p>
    <p class="span4">выдано</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input id ="ticketNumber" class="span4" value="00001"></input>
    <input id="paymentDate" class="span4" value="01/01/1970"></input>
    <input id="issueDate" class="span4" value="01/01/1970"></input>
</div>
</div>
<div id="contacts" class="span12">
    <div class="row">
        <p class="span8">Ф.И.О.</p>
        <p class="span4">Дата рождения</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input id="fio" class="span8" value="Иванов Иван Иванович"></input>
        <input id="birthDate" class="span4" value="01/01/1970"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="span4">Телефон: рабочий</p>
        <p class="span4">мобильный</p>
        <p class="span4">Электронная почта</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input id="workNumber" class="span4" value="+79001234567"></input>
        <input id="mobileNumber" class="span4" value="+79001234567"></input>
        <input id="email" class="span4" value="ivan@gmail.com"></input>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="LPU" class="span12">
    <div class="row">
        <p class="span8">ЛПУ</p>
        <p class="span4">структурное подразделение</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input id="lpu" class="span8" value="МУЗ ЧГКБ №1"></input>
        <input id="structuralSubdivision" class="span4" value="хирургическое отделение"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="span4">Должность</p>
        <p class="span4">Категория</p>
        <p class="span4">Присвоена</p>  
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input id="position" class="span4" value="хирург"></input>
        <select id="category" class="span4 selectpicker" value="вторая">
            <option>высшая</option>
            <option>первая</option>
            <option>вторая</option>
        </select>
        <input id="categoryDate" class="span4" value="01/01/1970"></input>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="diploma" class="span12">
    <div class="row">
        <p class="span4">Диплом серия и номер</p>
        <p class="span4">Специальность по диплому</p>
        <p class="span4">Ученая степень звание</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input id="diploma" class="span4" value="123"></input>
        <input id="speciality" class="span4" value="кардиохирургия"></input>
        <input id="degree" class="span4" value="Доктор медицины"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="span4">Второе образование</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input id="secondDiploma" class="span12" value="Анестезиолог"></input>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="participation" class="span12">
    <div class="row">
        <p class="span12">Участие в деятельности палаты</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="checkbox" class="span1">согласен работать в комитете</input>
        <select class="span8 selectpicker" value="По медицинской этике">
            <option>По медицинской этике</option>
            <option>по правовым вопросам и независимой экспертизе в сфере здравоохранения</option>
            <option>по образованию и науке в сфере здравоохранения</option>
            <option>контрольно-дисциплинарный</option>
            <option>по социальной поддержке и защите интересов медицинских работников</option>
            <option>по развитию рынка услуг в сфере здравоохранения</option>
            <option>по молодежной политике и поддержке медицинских специалистов</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="buttons" class="span12">
    <a href="#" id="save" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini"><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i> Сохранить</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini"><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i> Отменить</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using input as `<input id="diploma" class="span4" value="123" />`

Comment: Are you sure, your code is within the `document.ready` handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many elements that have the ID "diploma". ID are unique, you can't use a ID 2 times.

In your code, you're using it for `<div id="diploma" class="span12">` and for `<input id="diploma" class="span4" value="123"></input>`

Your input should also be written like this : `<input id="diploma" class="span4" value="123" />`

I change the ID of your `div` for "diplomas" and it works now : [**Here's the fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yc393/)

Answer (score 2):

Id's are UNIQUE. Assign a different id  to the second input with this id , i also suggest that you remove the end tag for input.

Answer (score 1):

Change input tag as

`<input id="diploma" type="text" class="span4" value="123" />`

Also make sure ID's are unique. IDs are meant to be unique in the document, if you have it elsewhere it would be invalid.